# how to optimize snap svg animations

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg, svg-animate

I have a snap svg animation which animates a bunch of circles, and draws a line between them if they are within a certain proximity of each other. However, I realize that there is a lot of optimizing I can do, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. I feel like it would be useful to

1. have a good example of proximity detection in snap
2. have some more information on optimizing animations in snap svg. It hasn't been easy to find.

Here is a working example of the animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/heaversm/sbj4W/1/

and here are the things I believe can be optimized:

---

Each circle calls its own animation function - the circles have all been added to a group, and I'm guessing there is a way to apply random motion to all members of a group that is more performant than call a function for each and every element within the group.

```
for (var i=0; i<this.drawingConfig.circles.amount;i++){
  ...
  this.animateSingle(circleShape);
}
```

---

The proximity function is awkward - for each circle, for each update cycle, I have to loop through an array of all the other circles and find out if the X and Y coordinates are close enough to draw a line to. Plus, that means you're getting duplicate lines, because each circle will draw a line to its neighbors, instead of having a single shared line between the two.

```
for (var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
  var nextCircle = circles[i].node;
  var nextCircleX = nextCircle.cx.baseVal.value;
  var distance = Math.abs(nextCircleX-thisCircleX);
  var proximity = mainModule.drawingConfig.circles.proximity;
  if (distance < proximity){

    var nextCircleY = nextCircle.cy.baseVal.value;
    var thisCircleY = shape.node.cy.baseVal.value;
    var distanceY = Math.abs(nextCircleY - thisCircleY);
    if (distanceY < proximity){

      var line = mainModule.s.line(thisCircleX, thisCircleY, nextCircleX, nextCircleY).attr({stroke: '#a6a8ab', strokeWidth: '1px'});
      mainModule.drawingConfig.circles.circleGroup.add(line);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Correspondingly, I each circle's animation function clears all the lines on the screen. Ideally all the circles would be sharing one update function, and in that function, you'd clear the lines.

```
Snap.animate(startX, animX, function (val) {

  var lines = Snap.selectAll('line');
  lines.remove();

  ...

}, mainModule.drawingConfig.circles.animTime);
```

Right now, I can tell the renderer can't keep up with all of the various animations / loops. Any help optimizing the above things (or anything else you can see that I'm doing weird, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try [compressing it](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor). Other than that I think you should try CodeReview...

Comment: I'd never heard of code review - thanks Zach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned this up by running only one animation loop, on a timer every 10ms, and animated the position of the circles by just giving them a slope and, each update, continuing them further along that slope. You can see an updated fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/heaversm/fJ6fj/

```
    var mainModule = {
  s: Snap("#svg"),
  drawingConfig: {
    circles: {
      amount: 20,
      sizeMin: 10,
      sizeMax: 20,
      proximity: 100,
      circleGroup: null,
      circleArray: [],
      animTime: 2000
    },
    canvas: {
      width: 800,
      height: 600
    }
  },

  init: function(){
    //this.sizeCanvas();
    this.makeCircles();
  },

  sizeCanvas: function(){
    $('#svg').width(800).height(600);
  },

  makeCircles: function(){
    this.drawingConfig.circles.circleGroup = this.s.g();

    for (var i=0; i<this.drawingConfig.circles.amount;i++){
      var circleX = this.randomNumber(0, this.drawingConfig.canvas.width);
      var circleY = this.randomNumber(0, this.drawingConfig.canvas.height);
      var circleRadius = this.randomNumber(this.drawingConfig.circles.sizeMin,this.drawingConfig.circles.sizeMax);
      var circleFill = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
      var circleShape = this.s.circle(circleX, circleY, circleRadius);
      circleShape.attr({
        fill: circleFill
      });
      this.drawingConfig.circles.circleGroup.add(circleShape);

      var circleIncline = this.setIncline();
      var circleObj = { incline: circleIncline, shape: circleShape };

      this.drawingConfig.circles.circleArray.push(circleObj);

    }

    this.update();


  },

  setIncline: function(){
    return { incX: this.randomNumber(-5,5), incY: this.randomNumber(-5,5) }
  },

  update: function(){

    var lines = Snap.selectAll('line');
    lines.remove();

    for (var i=0; i<this.drawingConfig.circles.amount; i++){
      var circle = this.drawingConfig.circles.circleArray[i];
      var circleX = circle.shape.node.cx.animVal.value;
      var circleY = circle.shape.node.cy.animVal.value;
      this.move(circle,circleX,circleY);

      for (var j=0;j<i;j++){
        if (i != j){
          var circle2 = this.drawingConfig.circles.circleArray[j];
          var circle2X = circle2.shape.node.cx.animVal.value;
          var circle2Y = circle2.shape.node.cy.animVal.value;
          var dist = mainModule.distance(circleX,circleY,circle2X,circle2Y);
          if (dist <= mainModule.drawingConfig.circles.proximity){ //
            var lineWeight = 10/dist;
            var line = mainModule.s.line(circleX, circleY, circle2X, circle2Y).attr({stroke: '#a6a8ab', strokeWidth: '1px'});
          }

          if (dist <= 10) { //collision
            circle.incline = mainModule.setIncline();
            circle2.incline = mainModule.setIncline();
          }

        }
      }

    }

    setTimeout(function(){ mainModule.update(); },10);

  },

  distance: function(circleX,circleY,circle2X,circle2Y){
    var distX = circle2X - circleX;
    var distY = circle2Y - circleY;
    distX = distX*distX;
    distY = distY*distY;
    return Math.sqrt(distX + distY);
  },

  move: function(circle,curX,curY){
    if (curX > this.drawingConfig.canvas.width || curX < 0) {
      circle.incline.incX = -circle.incline.incX;
    }
    if (curY > this.drawingConfig.canvas.height || curY < 0) {
      circle.incline.incY = -circle.incline.incY;
    }
    curX = curX + circle.incline.incX;
    curY = curY + circle.incline.incY;

    if (curX > this.drawingConfig.canvas.width) {
      curX = this.drawingConfig.canvas.width;
      circle.incline = this.setIncline();
    } else if (curX < 0) {
      curX = 0;
      circle.incline = this.setIncline();
    }

    if (curY > this.drawingConfig.canvas.height) {
      curY = this.drawingConfig.canvas.height;
      circle.incline = this.setIncline();
    } else if (curY < 0) {
      curY = 0;
      circle.incline = this.setIncline();
    }

    circle.shape.attr({ cx: curX, cy: curY });

  },

  randomNumber: function(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
  },

  getBounds: function(shape){
    shapeBox = shape.node.getBoundingClientRect();
  }

}

mainModule.init();
```